# Half Life Formula ~ Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

`Nt = N0e-λt`

N0 is the initial quantity
Nt is the quantity that still remains after a time t,
t1/2 is the half-life
τ is the mean lifetime
λ is the decay constant

I am pretty stuck on how to make this into a formula for objective-c and I require it.

```
double sourceStart = [textField.text doubleValue];
double sourceNow = 0;
double daysBetween = 8;

if (textField.text.length > 0) {
    //Find how many half lives have been accumulated
    double totalNumberOfHalfLives = daysBetween / sourceHalfLife;
    //Find the factor
    double reductionFactor = pow(0.5, totalNumberOfHalfLives);
    //Find the source strength now
    double sourceNow = sourceStart * reductionFactor;
}
```

I'm assuming I need something a long the lines of this? or completely wrong.

Then, I also need to be able to find how many days have passed between a certain period of days, for instance. Start Date = Apr 15th Now Date = Apr 25th, 10 days between.. How do I work that out in objective c? As well as my original question.

Comment: Are you trying to solve for `Nt`?

Comment: @paulGriffiths Yes Nt is what I require

Comment: What bits of data do you have? Your question references `t1/2` and `τ` but these are not in your formula, which is rearranged from a version that does contain them. Do you already have `N0`, `λ` and `t`?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I apologise, N0 would be `daysBetween` and `mean lifetime (τ): 36.06737602014
decay constant (λ): 0.027725887224` are constant values for a t1/2 of 25 as `t1/2 = ln(2)τ = ln(2)/λ`

Comment: @paulgriffiths you can also write the formula like this `Nt = N0(1/2)t/t1/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it (in straight C, but it'll work as-is in Objective-C, and you can extract the logic easily enough):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double start_quantity = 100;
    double half_life = 8;
    double days = 16;
    double end_quantity = start_quantity * pow(0.5, days / half_life);

    printf("After %.1f days with a half life of %.1f days, %.1f decays to %.1f.\
n",
            days, half_life, start_quantity, end_quantity);

    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src$ ./halflife
After 16.0 days with a half life of 8.0 days, 100.0 decays to 25.0.
paul@local:~/src$
```

For the second part of your question, you can store dates in an `NSDate`, and use the `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method to get the time between them in seconds. Something like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{ 
    @autoreleasepool {
        const int kSecsInADay = 86400;

        NSDate * startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-16 * kSecsInADay];
        NSDate * endDate = [NSDate date];

        NSTimeInterval seconds_diff = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        double days_diff = seconds_diff / kSecsInADay;

        NSLog(@"There are %.1f days between %@ and %@.", days_diff,
              [startDate description], [endDate description]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
There are 16.0 days between 2014-04-09 21:41:12 +0000 and 2014-04-25 21:41:12 +0000.
```

Notes:

- `[NSDate date]` returns an `NSDate` object representing the current time.
- `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds]` returns an `NSDate` object that's `seconds` seconds away from the current time. In this case, I've created it exactly 16 days before the current date. Based on the comments, in your case you'll also want to create `startDate` with `[NSDate date]`, and then store it somewhere so you can calculate the difference between it and the current time at some point in the future.

Comment: This works excellently paul, thank you very much. Without trying to pester you, would you have any idea or at least to pointer me in the direction of solving my next issue? That is counting the days between a set period of dates?

Comment: Depends on what format your dates are in. If you're using Objective-C and you have them in `NSDate`, then you'd want to look at `NSDate`'s `timeIntervalSinceDate:` method, which will give you the difference in seconds, and you can convert that to days easily enough. With straight C, you'd look into the `difftime()` function.

Comment: Obviously if you don't actually have the dates from somewhere, and just want to create them, you'll need to populate an `NSDate` or a `struct tm` or two before doing that. I can give you an example if you let me know how you need to do it.

Comment: basically, someone will create their "source" by placing in it's current strength, the value will be saved and so will the date most likely in a userdefaults mutable array so it will take the date based on what date their ios is at, then when they check up on the decay it will tell them based on their current date against their saved date.

Comment: OK, so in both cases, the date just comes from the current time, just at two different times? Give me a few mins to knock something together.

Comment: Thank you again buddy, you've been a great help!